# Accessibility Service Control Google Map Android

Tags: android, google-maps, accessibilityservice

i'm programming the project to use remote bluetooth for controlling android tablet. I can control some applications via my remote but Google Maps i can't. I tried to use Accessibility Service to control google map, but i'm not successful. I could got the event click the button and use AccessibilityService.GESTURE_DOUBLETAP but it's not affect the google maps.
I can't use bluetooth button to zoom in, zoom out, move the map view. May someone have experiences with google map accessibility service can help me? Thank you so much for the support.

This is my code.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQBTN.png)

I tried to use Accessibility Service to control google map, but i'm not successful. I could got the event click the button and use AccessibilityService.GESTURE_DOUBLETAP but it's not affect the google maps.
I expect I can send the performance click to handle view in Google map.

Comment: Did you resolve ?